# Where/how does the kernel loads statically linked modules?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Looking at [init/main.c#start_kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/init/main.c#L531) it's not clear where the statically linked kernel modules are loaded, neither how the kernel gets a list of them.

So, **where are the statically linked kernel modules loaded**?

Comment: Statically linked modules aren't "loaded" separately. They are _linked_ into the `vmlinux` image. So, when the kernel is loaded [by the boot loader], all statically linked modules are already in it. This is analogous to a program: `void foo(void) { } int main(void) { return 0; }` The function `foo` is "statically" linked into the program executable. However, `libc.so` is dynamically linked. Any statically linked kernel modules are like `foo` and any dynamically linked modules are like `libc.so` [and get a `.ko` suffix]. The latter must be loaded via `modprobe`, etc.

Comment: @CraigEstey but shouldn't the linux kernel know where they are in order to call initialization stuff on each one?

Comment: It does. When you create a static kernel module, you use certain macros to define the callback to the "init" function. (e.g.) `static int __init myinit(void) { return 0; }` and then (e.g.) `device_initcall(myinit);` This generates extra code/data/whatever similar to what `__attribute__((constructor))` does for a `gcc` built program

Comment: @CraigEstey looking at `device_initcall` it translates to `int init_module(void) __copy(initfn) __attribute__((alias(#initfn)));
` which is just an alias to the function in multiple places, it's still not clear how this initializes stuff. Some modules might need kernel structures to be ready, so how does it know how to wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For compiling a module "as a module", the corresponding `Kconfig` is set to `m`. If set to `y`, all the module code is compiled just like all the other "builtin" kernel source files, and the generated object files are added to all the rest of the "builtin" kernel object files, which are then linked together to create the `vmlinux` image. Therefore, as the bootloader loads this monolithic image into memory to boot the kernel, all the builtin modules are loaded with it. All that is required is for the functions marked with `module_init` to be called during initialization.

As to how that happens, the short answer is, unless the module source file is compiled "as a module", the `module_init` adds the given function address to an array of function addresses that are then called during initialization.

---

For the long answer, consider the `mkiss` module at `drivers/net/hamradio/mkiss.c`.

### Kconfig and Compiler Flags

The `Kconfig` is found in `drivers/net/hamradio/Kconfig`:

```
config MKISS
        tristate "Serial port KISS driver"
        depends on AX25 && TTY
        select CRC16
        help
          ...
          To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the module
          will be called mkiss.
```

The selection results in a `CONFIG_MKISS=y` or `CONFIG_MKISS=m` line in the `.config` file. This is then used in the `drivers/net/hamradio/Makefile`:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_MKISS)             += mkiss.o
```

So, if "builtin", `mkiss.o` is added to the list of targets `obj-y`. And if "module", it is added to `obj-m`. After some path processing, `obj-m` becomes `real-obj-m` in `scripts/Makefile.lib`, which is then used to determine the compiler flags:

```
part-of-module = $(if $(filter $(basename $@).o, $(real-obj-m)),y)

modkern_cflags =                                          \
        $(if $(part-of-module),                           \
                $(KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE) $(CFLAGS_MODULE), \
                $(KBUILD_CFLAGS_KERNEL) $(CFLAGS_KERNEL) $(modfile_flags))

c_flags        = -Wp,-MMD,$(depfile) $(NOSTDINC_FLAGS) $(LINUXINCLUDE)     \
                 -include $(srctree)/include/linux/compiler_types.h       \
                 $(_c_flags) $(modkern_cflags)                           \
                 $(basename_flags) $(modname_flags)
```

The takeaway here is that we get `$(KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE)` for modules, and `$(KBUILD_CFLAGS_KERNEL)` for builtin. These are defined in the top-level `Makefile`:

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS_KERNEL :=
KBUILD_CFLAGS_MODULE  := -DMODULE
```

### Initialization Function for Builtins

This difference in `MODULE` preprocessor macro definition is utilized in `include/linux/module.h` to provide alternate definitions to `module_init` (and `module_exit`):

```
#ifndef MODULE
/**
 * module_init() - driver initialization entry point
 * @x: function to be run at kernel boot time or module insertion
 *
 * module_init() will either be called during do_initcalls() (if
 * builtin) or at module insertion time (if a module).  There can only
 * be one per module.
 */
#define module_init(x)  __initcall(x);

/**
 * module_exit() - driver exit entry point
 * @x: function to be run when driver is removed
 *
 * module_exit() will wrap the driver clean-up code
 * with cleanup_module() when used with rmmod when
 * the driver is a module.  If the driver is statically
 * compiled into the kernel, module_exit() has no effect.
 * There can only be one per module.
 */
#define module_exit(x)  __exitcall(x);
#else /* MODULE */
...
```

### Tracking `initcall`

So, if builtin, `module_init` becomes `__initcall`, which is the same as `device_initcall`, as you can see in `include/linux/init.h`:

```
#define __initcall(fn) device_initcall(fn)
```

If you can follow all the macros:

```
#define device_initcall(fn)             __define_initcall(fn, 6)
#define __define_initcall(fn, id) ___define_initcall(fn, id, .initcall##id)
#define ___define_initcall(fn, id, __sec)                       \
        __unique_initcall(fn, id, __sec, __initcall_id(fn))

#define __unique_initcall(fn, id, __sec, __iid)                 \
        ____define_initcall(fn,                                 \
                __initcall_stub(fn, __iid, id),                 \
                __initcall_name(initcall, __iid, id),           \
                __initcall_section(__sec, __iid))

#ifdef CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_PREL32_RELOCATIONS
#define ____define_initcall(fn, __stub, __name, __sec)          \
        __define_initcall_stub(__stub, fn)                      \
        asm(".section   \"" __sec "\", \"a\"            \n"     \
            __stringify(__name) ":                      \n"     \
            ".long      " __stringify(__stub) " - .     \n"     \
            ".previous                                  \n");   \
        static_assert(__same_type(initcall_t, &fn));
#else
#define ____define_initcall(fn, __unused, __name, __sec)        \
        static initcall_t __name __used                         \
                __attribute__((__section__(__sec))) = fn;
#endif
```

or if you run the preprocessor, you arrive at something like this:

```
.section ".initcall6.init", "a"
__initcall__kmod_mkiss__502_979_mkiss_init_driver6:
.long mkiss_init_driver - .
.previous
```

which is adding a unique (for every distinct invocation of a given function) symbol with an (relative) address to the `mkiss_init_driver` function, in a section called `.initcall6.init`. The "6" here represents the `initcall` order for `device`. It goes:

```
0: pure
1: core
2: postcore
3: arch
4: subsys
5: fs
6: device
7: late
```

When all these object files are linked together, the `.initcallX.init` sections will be merged by the linker, and each such section will be an array of function pointers to be called in that stage during initialization. The definitions of these arrays can be found in `include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h`:

```
#define INIT_DATA_SECTION(initsetup_align)                              \
        .init.data : AT(ADDR(.init.data) - LOAD_OFFSET) {               \
                INIT_DATA                                               \
                INIT_SETUP(initsetup_align)                             \
                INIT_CALLS                                              \
                CON_INITCALL                                            \
                INIT_RAM_FS                                             \
        }

#define INIT_CALLS                                                      \
                __initcall_start = .;                                   \
                KEEP(*(.initcallearly.init))                            \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(0)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(1)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(2)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(3)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(4)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(5)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(rootfs)                                \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(6)                                     \
                INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(7)                                     \
                __initcall_end = .;

#define INIT_CALLS_LEVEL(level)                                         \
                __initcall##level##_start = .;                          \
                KEEP(*(.initcall##level##.init))                        \
                KEEP(*(.initcall##level##s.init))
```

Finally, you can see the iteration over these arrays in `init/main.c`:

```
static initcall_entry_t *initcall_levels[] __initdata = {
        __initcall0_start,
        __initcall1_start,
        __initcall2_start,
        __initcall3_start,
        __initcall4_start,
        __initcall5_start,
        __initcall6_start,
        __initcall7_start,
        __initcall_end,
};
...
static void __init do_initcalls(void)
{
        ...
        for (level = 0; level < ARRAY_SIZE(initcall_levels) - 1; level++) {
                ...
                do_initcall_level(level, command_line);
        }
        ...
}

static void __init do_initcall_level(int level, char *command_line)
{
        ...
        for (fn = initcall_levels[level]; fn < initcall_levels[level+1]; fn++)
                do_one_initcall(initcall_from_entry(fn));
}

int __init_or_module do_one_initcall(initcall_t fn)
{
        ...
        ret = fn();
        ...
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: this is soooooo cool. Wish I had more points to give you for kernel explanations